# How to prevent encapsulation of an imported global style in Angular component?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, scss-mixins

Is there any way that importing a global style (in my case these are mixins from Bootstrap) does not affect the encapsulation of selectors in the component?

Let me explain this with an example:

**/style/bootstrap.scss** – Changing the default values of Bootstrap variables:

```
@forward '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap' with (
  $body-bg: color.$white,
  $body-color: color.$dark
);
```

**/component/foo/foo.scss** – Component style where I use useful Bootstraps mixins and variables:

```
@use 'bootstrap' as bootstrap;

figure {
  display: none;

  @include bootstrap.media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    display: block;
    border-radius: bootstrap.$border-radius-lg;
  }
}
```

**/component/foo/foo.html** – A component view where I use Bootstrap classes:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <figure>...</figure>
      <button class="btn">Foo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The effect of this solution is that Angular adds its attributes to Bootstrap's global classes. And this is all because I am using `@use 'bootstrap'`.

[image: Unnecessary scoping on bootstrap classes]

This is completely unnecessary, and forces me to use `!important` when I want to change the default property values of Bootstrap classes.

So does it go to disable scoping/encapsulation for Bootstrap without using `ViewEncapsulation.None`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you are importing the entirety of bootstrap in your component, including the classes. This can't be what you want :). Because as you can see, angular sees those classes, and encapsulates them.

To access the variables and functions you can do the following:

```
@use '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@forward '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@forward '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@forward '~bootstrap/scss/variables' with (
  $body-bg: color.$white,
  $body-color: color.$dark
);
```

```css
@use 'bootstrap';

figure {
  display: none;

  @include bootstrap.media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    display: block;
    border-radius: bootstrap.$border-radius-lg;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this approach, I don't have Bootstrap variables overwritten by me.

Comment: @PaulK. I've updated my answer. I haven't really used bootstrap so it's more of a guess. But by judging their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/) this is the way to go

Comment: I think that this would work if using `@import`. Unfortunately, in this case, the variable file uses `@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");` among others. And using `@use` and `@forward`, the precompiler cannot locate this mixin. I get `SassError: Undefined mixin`.